# SQL Server DB Engine Memory Leakage

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, memory-leaks

We have a Windows Form Application and the back-end of the application is SQL Server Express 2005/2008. Our application can be installed on Windows XP SP3/ Windows Vista/ Windows 7.

We have observed huge memory leakage in SQL Server Express.

Normally, there are two process running even if the application is not used by the user:

1. A polling process to check the availability of files. (If files are not available then, only one query is fired to check some configuration setting)
2. A Scheduling process. (This process fires a query every minute to check for any scheduled task)

We have observed that the memory usage of the SQL Server (sqlsrvr.exe) keeps on increasing.  In around an hour, the memory usage reaches upto 1GB and it never comes down.

We have also noticed that, if the interval of the polling process is increased, then the memory usage increases gradually but, it does increase.

The higher memory usage by SQL server downgrades the machine performance and  the performance of all other applications running on the machine.

Please provide suggestions to control the memory usage of SQL server in this case.

PFB the details:

1. Software causing issue :SQL Server 2005/2008 Express editions (named instance)
2. Operating Systems on which issue can be simulated  : Windows XP SP3/ Windows Vista/ Windows 7

Regards,

Abhineet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is designed to take all the memory on the system and use it for its internal cache. You should never run anything else on the same machine as SQL Server. This is not a leak, is the intended and desired behavior. By design. See [Memory Manager Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280359%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

As a special case SQL Server Express edition limits its internal buffer pool size to 1Gb. The buffer pool is not the only memory consumed by SQL Server though. You can further limit the SQL Server buffer pool size by specifying a value for [`max server memory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried setting the max server memory to 1GB. But even if my machine is idle the memory used by sqlsrvr.exe keeps on increasing.

Comment: Setting SQL Server express to 1GB is a no-op, as I explained 1Gb is the default for Express.